# Twig PHP Renderer and Tempo JS Renderer together?

Tags: javascript, php, twig, tempo

I have some issues using the Twig engine and the Tempo engine together in a project.

```
<ul id="tweets" class="list-unstyled">
               <li data-template>
                   <img src="#" data-src="{{author}}" />
                   <h3>{{uuid}}</h3>
                   <p>{{comment}}<span>, {{age}} <small>ago</small></span></p>
               </li>
   </ul>
```

the {{author}} e.g. must be rendered by Tempo and is filled by an async ajax call. When Twig renders the PHP it fills the bracket tags with empty strings because the tags are unknown or null at this time. Both engines have the same syntax.

Any ideas? Thx in advise.

Comment: My first idea would be to use just one templating engine. I guess you've thought of that though?

Comment: sure...but thats the very last option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Tempo [docs](http://tempojs.com/#advanced):

> In order to make it easier to use Tempo with other frameworks such as Django, you can configure Tempo to use surrounding braces other than the default {{ ... }} and {% ... %}.
>
> To do this you pass the var_braces and tag_braces parameters to the Tempo.prepare function. These will be split down the middle to form the left and right braces.

```
Tempo.prepare('marx-brothers', {'var_braces' : '\\[\\[\\]\\]', 'tag_braces' : '\\[\\?\\?\\]'});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ugly, but it should work:

```
<img src="#" data-src="{{'{{author}}'}}" />
```

Twig will now render `{{author}}`.